# Is there a way to show Altair Tooltip all the time?

Tags: altair

I like the way tooltip looks way more than when I add text as labels for the points in my plot, is there a way to make it visible wether the mouse is on it or not?

I looked it up but haven't found any solutions, maybe with messing around with conditions?

example code from doc if you have ideas you'd like to test out :

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.cars()

alt.Chart(source).mark_circle(size=60).encode(
    x='Horsepower',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon',
    color='Origin',
    tooltip=['Name', 'Origin', 'Horsepower', 'Miles_per_Gallon']
).interactive()
```

thank u :)

Comment: What you want to do is annotate with a string? See this:[Is there a way to display the value of a mark next to the mark in Altair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71720663/is-there-a-way-to-display-the-value-of-a-mark-next-to-the-mark-in-altair)

Comment: yes thank you, I know how to do that,, but I prefer the look of the tooltip and i'm looking for a way to display it w/o the mouse hovering :)

Comment: Can the label be annotated while leaving the tooltip, but are you asking for anything else?

Comment: sorry if i wasn't clear, i want the tooltip to stay constantly, with or without mouse hovering, i need the tooltip to act as a label/annotation, is that possible? That's all I'm asking

Comment: Is wanting to display your tooltip at all times the same as wanting to include all of the tooltip information in the label?

Comment: No, i like the specific look of the tooltip !

Comment: Do you mean that you want the tooltip for each data points to always be visible? That would mean a lot of overlapping text that would not be readable in your example. Or do you want a single single datapoint's tooltip to be visible?

Comment: @joelostblom yes that's what I mean ! It's not gonna be in a graph with too many points :) do you know if it's possible?

Comment: I don't think you can get a single tooltip to always be visible. You might be able to change the CSS so that all tooltips are always visible, but then you would need to create a separate graph that creates a tooltip for just one of the data points. It seems easier to use a text annotation as @r-beginners suggested and I added an answer with how to style this text

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment above, I think the easiest way to do this is adding a styled text box. You can see [an example of how to style it in this issue](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/2430#issuecomment-812090575), which I also pasted below:

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

cars = data.cars()
chart = alt.Chart(cars).mark_circle().encode(
        alt.X('Miles_per_Gallon', scale=alt.Scale(domain=(5,50))),
        y='Weight_in_lbs')
corl = cars[['Miles_per_Gallon','Weight_in_lbs']].corr().iloc[0,1]

text = alt.Chart({'values':[{}]}).mark_text(
    align="left", baseline="top"
).encode(
    x=alt.value(5),  # pixels from left
    y=alt.value(5),  # pixels from top
    text=alt.value([f"r: {corl:.3f}", 'Line 2']))

box = alt.Chart({'values':[{}]}).mark_rect(stroke='black', color='orange').encode(
    x=alt.value(3),
    x2=alt.value(50),
    y=alt.value(3),
    y2=alt.value(30))

chart + box + text + chart.transform_regression('Miles_per_Gallon','Weight_in_lbs').mark_line()
```

[image]